# How to keep Spring boot application running when Oracle connection fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application written in `Spring boot version 2.7.2` and connected to an Oracle database. How can my application still run even if it can't connect to the database (wrong url or dead database)

- configuration:

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
    log-startup-info: true
  profiles:
    active: production
  sql:
    init:
      continue-on-error: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:thanbv
    username: thanbv
```

The application will not be able to run when my database has been shut down.

```
 Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException
```

- I tried adding this configuration but it still doesn't work:

```yaml
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      continue-on-error: true
```

How do I keep my application running regardless of whether the connection is successful with the database?

Comment: At first, I would try to use ```?autoreconnect=true``` in your jdbc-url. If that isn't enough you should initialize your own pooled datasource. There are some more options for econnecting and so on.

Comment: What do you mean with still run? As it keeps running when it already is running and the database goes down, or as in startup without a database?

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

it works for me